# How to Render React Components with Data from localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I'm building a React app where a lot of the content of the react app is pulled from the localStorage. Rather than using a database, when the app is run, the first thing that is done is the localStorage is populated with the data, then the HTML is built from the JS using the data from the localStorage....

But now with React, I'm starting to move from hard coding the information in, to using it from the localStorage. However, it seems the react components are rendered before the JS that loads the localStorage. Using console.log, I found that the React rendering was done before anything else. How would I go about making sure the HTML (from the react components) isn't implemented until AFTER the JS is done that builds the localStorage?

**MAIN APP COMPONENT**

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("Constructing App");
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <Navigation {this.title: "Something based on localStorage"/>
     </div>
    )}
 }
```

**NAVIGATION COMPONENT**

```
function Navigation(props) {
  console.log("Constructing Nav");

  return ("stuff here pulled from props like props.title")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the local storage `getItem` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) - 
`localStorage.getItem('myData');`

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    state: {
      myData: {}      
    }  
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const myData = localStorage.getItem('myData');
    // set the state with the data
    this.setState({myData});
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <Navigation title={this.state.myData} />
     </div>
    )}
 }
```

Comment: this does not solve the issue at all. This gets the localStorage. But the problem is that that would get the localStorage BEFORE it was populated by my JQuery. I need the React to load the components AFTER the storage is populated

Comment: where is `jQuery` in you r post? this is the first time you mentioned it, and how is `jQuery` relevant to `localStorage`?

Comment: @user10059818 you never mentioned `jQuery` in your question.

Comment: @user10059818 Anyway if you need the data before the component is mounting you can do it in the `constructor` method.

Comment: I could call my "loadMyDataInStorage()" function however, due to async, React will continue to render everything else after it calls the function.... Meaning that everything still is rendered before the LoadMyDatainStorage() function is finished.

Comment: @user10059818 where is the async in this code? `localStorage.getItem` is not asynchronous. its just depends on what life cycle of react you are using, one that invoked before or after mounting

Comment: again its not getLocalStorage that is the problem. its the function that I have loadMyDataInStorage() which puts information INTO the localStorage. that takes time and is not complete until after the Render of React

Comment: @user10059818 include the real problem in your question then. Agan i don't know why your function is asynchronous as `localStorage.setItem` is not async as well. In general, when you have a sync functionality and you want to invoke something when it's done, then you can pass a callback or use async await (you would need to return a promise to create a micro task).

Comment: @user10059818 *its the function that I have loadMyDataInStorage() which puts information INTO the localStorage*. It doesn't make sense to use localStorage as single source of truth then (this is what you're trying to do). You have XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to revise your code some:

```
class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("Constructing App");
        this.state={
          fromLocal:''
        }
      }
      componentDidMount(){
        let newSearchColumns = localStorage.getItem('searchColumns');
        this.setState({fromLocal: newSearchColumns})
      }

      render() {
        return (
        <div>
          <Navigation title= {this.state.fromLocal}/>
         </div>
        )}
     }
```

You should research the following:
[Lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)
and 
[Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage)

Answer (score 0):

The default methods of a React Component are run in a certain sequence ([the "lifecycle" of the component](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/lifecycle_methods_overview.html)).

If you have operations you want to perform, like building localStorage, you can place them earlier in the sequence.

Initialization and Mounting both occur before rendering, so you can build localStorage in either of those phases. Specifically, try overriding the componentWillMount() method.